# Coloring caption label in ConTeXt

Tags: color, captions, context, context-lmtx

I am trying to color the caption label and their numbering (e.g., Figure 2 and Table 1, etc.). As a side note, I also use other names for such labels (Gambar 2 instead of Figure 2, for example).

I tried using the defined color `\definecolor[notsoblue][c=0.756, m=0.378, y=0, k=0.388]` directly at `\setuplabeltext` such as `\setuplabeltext[en][figure=\notsoblue{Gambar~}]`, which quite works but makes the entry on the List of Figures blue as well. I need to change the color of labels under the figures only and keep their color on LoF black.

Where should I fiddle with the color setting to color my caption labels? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, now I am just guessing, since you do not provide an example. You might look for `\setupcaption`. Below is a complete example:

```
\definecolor
  [notsoblue]
  [c=0.756, m=0.378, y=0, k=0.388] 

\setuplabeltext
  [en]
  [figure=Gambar~]

\setupcaption
  [figure]
  [headcolor=notsoblue]

\setupinteraction
  [state=start,
   style=,
   color=,
   contrastcolor=]

\starttext

\completelist
  [figure]

\section[title=A section]

\samplefile{ward}

\startplacefloat
  [figure]
  [title={Bla bla bla},
   reference=fig:foo]
  \blackrule[width=\textwidth,height=3cm]
\stopplacefloat

\samplefile{ward}

See \in{Gambar}[fig:foo].
\stoptext
```

[image: output]

Comment: \setupcaption solves it.  I really need to re-read manuals.